# How does Ansible skip the human interaction page during package installation

Tags: mysql, ansible

I would like to upgrade MySQL from 5.7 to 8.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04

I installed the package with the command :

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb
```

And I have this page pop up and need to manually select the option.
[image]

Is there any way I can do automatic upgrade MySQL by Ansible?

I am very new to Ansible, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to use the normal [`apt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html) module to install your .deb file:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - apt:
        deb: /path/to/mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb
```

---

To answer your question about suppressing the configuration dialog:

You can skip that dialog yourself by setting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable to `noninteractive` before running `dpkg` or `apt` commands:

```
sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb
```

The `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable can take other values; you can read more [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-debian_frontend-apt-get-variable-for-ubuntu-debian/).